# Column name in separate table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to analyze application data, and it stores data in separate table from definition (column names). Something like this:

```
Data table1:
id | 1234 | 1235 | 1236
---|------|------|-----
 1 | val1 | val2 | val3

Model:
tableID | colID | Name
--------|-------|-----
 table1 | 1234  | Name
 table1 | 1235  | DOB
 table1 | 1236  | Sex
 table2 | 1237  | Manager
etc...
```

I want to get this data like this:

```
Data:
id | Name | DOB  | Sex
---|------|------|-----
 1 | val1 | val2 | val3
```

Is it possible? Additional problem is that in each data table there might be different number of columns.

UPD.
Problem solved by @Prdp
Though, i've changed query a little bit:

```
DECLARE @col_list VARCHAR(max)

SET @col_list = Stuff((SELECT ',' + Quotename(af.ColID) + ' as ' + Quotename(af.Name)
                       FROM   [Model].dbo.Fields af
                       WHERE  af.[App.ID] = 123
                       FOR xml path ('')), 1, 1, '')
EXEC('select '+@col_list+' from [Data].dbo.[123]')
```

Comment: It's possible, but 1: This is a terrible desing that should be changed, and 2: I would suggest replacing the column names in the presentation layer, not on the sql level. The only way I know of to do such a thing in sql requires using dynamic sql and that's usually not worth the truble.

Comment: Yes, i know that this is terrible design for SQL. But, this is not my application. I'm just need to analyze some of its data. And, i suppose, this was made so users can change field names (columns in DB) in application. Thats why there is separate tables, one that contains application model, and other with data itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments better to handle this in application layer. If in case you want a sql solution then you need dynamic query

```
DECLARE @col_list VARCHAR(8000)

SET @col_list = Stuff((SELECT ',' + Quotename(colID) + ' as ' + Quotename(NAME)
                       FROM   Model
                       WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                      FROM   information_schema.columns
                                      WHERE  table_name = 'Data'
                                             AND Cast(colID AS VARCHAR(50)) = column_name)
                       FOR xml path ('')), 1, 1, '')

EXEC('select '+@col_list+' from data')
```

Comment: This exactly what i needed. Thanks!